# Passing named arguments in launch.json

Tags: spring-boot, visual-studio-code

I am trying to pass named arguments to `launch.json` as program arguments in VSCode.

```
--myArgument=My Argument Value
```

So that I can catch this named property in Spring Boot as an external property.

I have tried the `"args"` key but this passes them to the main function.

Is there a way to achieve this in the VSCode Java Debugger?

Comment: who do you want to give these arguments, if they are arguments to the debugger find the property for your particular debugger

Comment: Just trying to proof a concept

Comment: with the extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable you can use a couple of methods to pass text to the launch arguments, eq. `file.content` to use some part of a config file or `selectedText`